# What is the benefit of immediate down-casting?

Tags: java, coding-style

I've been looking at a lot of code recently (for my own benefit, as I'm still learning to program), and I've noticed a number of Java projects (from what appear to be well respected programmers) wherein they use some sort of *immediate down-casting*.

I actually have multiple examples, but here's one that I pulled straight from the code:

```
public Set<Coordinates> neighboringCoordinates() {
    HashSet<Coordinates> neighbors = new HashSet<Coordinates>();
    neighbors.add(getNorthWest());
    neighbors.add(getNorth());
    neighbors.add(getNorthEast());
    neighbors.add(getWest());
    neighbors.add(getEast());
    neighbors.add(getSouthEast());
    neighbors.add(getSouth());
    neighbors.add(getSouthWest());
    return neighbors;
}
```

And from the same project, here's another (perhaps more concise) example:

```
private Set<Coordinates> liveCellCoordinates = new HashSet<Coordinates>();
```

In the first example, you can see that the method has a return type of `Set<Coordinates>` - however, that specific method will always only return a `HashSet` - and no other type of `Set`.

In the second example, `liveCellCoordinates` is initially defined as a `Set<Coordinates>`, but is immediately turned into a `HashSet`.

And it's not just this single, specific project - I've found this to be the case in multiple projects.

I am curious as to what the logic is behind this? Is there some code-conventions that would consider this good practice? Does it make the program faster or more efficient somehow? What benefit would it have?

Comment: These are actually examples of up-casting (from a specific type to a broader type). See, e.g., the [Wikipedia entry on downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting).

Comment: @TedHopp Take the second example I provided, in that example I start as a `Set`, and then convert to a `HashSet` (I believe the `HashSet` is more specific than the `Set`). Wouldn't that be down-casting? Since I'm going from a broad-type of `Set` to a specific type of `HashSet`?

Comment: In the second example, you are creating a `HashSet` and converting it to a `Set` when assigning it to `liveCellCoordinates`. No `Set` object exists until the `new` expression is evaluated and no `Set` is being converted to a `HashSet`.

Comment: @TedHopp Okay, thanks for the clarification. I was confused about where the "starting point" was, I thought it was starting with the `Set`, I didn't know it was the other way around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are designing a method signature, it is usually better to only pin down what needs to be pinned down. In the first example, by specifying only that the method returns a `Set` (instead of a `HashSet` specifically), the implementer is free to change the implementation if it turns out that a `HashSet` is not the right data structure. If the method had been declared to return a `HashSet`, then all code that depended on the object being specifically a `HashSet` instead of the more general `Set` type would also need to be revised.

A realistic example would be if it was decided that `neighboringCoordinates()` needed to return a thread-safe `Set` object. As written, this would be very simple to do—replace the last line of the method with:

```
return Collections.synchronizedSet(neighbors);
```

As it turns out, the `Set` object returned by `synchronizedSet()` is not assignment-compatible with `HashSet`. Good thing the method was declared to return a `Set`!

A similar consideration applies to the second case. Code in the class that uses `liveCellCoordinates` shouldn't need to know anything more than that it is a `Set`. (In fact, in the first example, I would have expected to see:

```
Set<Coordinates> neighbors = new HashSet<Coordinates>();
```

at the top of the method.)

Comment: +1: Its about being deliberate about your choices so your minimum requirements are clear.  Using types which imply things which are not actually required is harder to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Because now if they change the type in the future, any code depending on neighboringCoordinates does not have to be updated.

Let's you had:

```
HashedSet<Coordinates> c = neighboringCoordinates()
```

Now, let's say they change their code to use a different implementation of set.  Guess what, you have to change your code too.

But, if you have:

```
Set<Coordinates> c = neighboringCoordinates()
```

As long as their collection still implements set, they can change whatever they want internally without affecting your code.

Basically, it's just being the least specific possible (within reason) for the sake of hiding internal details.  Your code only cares that it can access the collection as a set.  It doesn't care what specific type of set it is, if that makes sense.  Thus, why make your code be coupled to a HashedSet?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, that the method will always only return a HashSet is an implementation detail that users of the class should not have to know.  This frees the developer to use a different implementation if it is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

The design principle in play here is "always prefer specifying abstract types".

`Set` is abstract; there is no such concrete class `Set` - it's an interface, which is by definition abstract. The method's *contract* is to return a `Set` - it's up the developer to chose what *kind* of `Set` to return.

You should do this with fields as well, eg:

```
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>;
```

not

```
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>;
```

Later, you may want to change to using a `LinkedList` - specifying the abstract type allows you to do this with no code changes (except for the initializtion of course).

Answer (score 2):

The question is how you want to use the variable. e.g. is it in your context *important* that it is a `HashSet`? If not, you should say what you need, and this is just a `Set`.

Things were different if you would use e.g. `TreeSet` here. Then you would lose the information that the `Set` is sorted, and if your algorithm relies on this property, changing the implementation to `HashSet` would be a disaster. In this case the best solution would be to write `SortedSet<Coordinates> set = new TreeSet<Coordinates>();`. Or imagine you would write `List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();`: That's ok if you want to use `list` just as list, but you wouldn't be able to use the `LinkedList` as deque any longer, as methods like `offerFirst` or `peekLast` are not on the `List` interface.

So the general rule is: Be as general as possible, but as specific as needed. Ask yourself what you really need. Does a certain interface provide all functionality and promises you need? If yes, then use it. Else be more specific, use another interface or the class itself as type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another reason. It's because more general (abstract) types have fewer behaviors which is good because there is less room to mess up.

For example, let's say you implemented a method like this: `List<User> users = getUsers();` when in fact you could have used a more abstract type like this: `Collection<User> users = getUsers();`. Now Bob might assume wrongly that your method returns users in alphabetic order and create a bug. Had you used `Collection`, there wouldn't have been such confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple.

In your example, the method returns `Set`. From an API designer's point of view this has one significant advantage, compared to returning `HashSet`.

If at some point, the programmer decides to use `SuperPerformantSetForDirections` then he can do it without changing the public API, if the new class extends `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is "*code to the interface*".

The reason for this is that in 99.9% of the cases you just want the behavior from `HashSet/TreeSet/WhateverSet` that conforms to the `Set`-interface implemented by all of them.   It keeps your code simpler, and the only reason you actually need to say `HashSet` is to specify what *behavior* the Set you need has.

As you may know HashSet is relatively fast but returns items in seemingly random order.  TreeSet is a bit slower, but returns items in alphabetical order.    Your code does not care, as long as it behaves like a Set.

This gives simpler code, easier to work with.

Note that the typical choices for a Set is a HashSet, Map is HashMap and List is ArrayList.  If you use a non-typical (for you) implementation, there should be a good reason for it (like, needing the alphabetical sorting) and that reason should be put in a comment next to the `new` statement.  Makes the life easier for future maintainers.